# Django View check second model for value

Tags: python, django

I'm somewhat new to Django so please bear with me here.  I have a three models in my app, Company, Articles, and Transcripts.  Both Articles and Transcripts have a foreignkey() field that links to the Company model.  In my main view I list all of the companies, but I would like to indicate if there is an article or transcript for each of those companies.

Here are the models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    stock_symbol = models.CharField(max_length=5, unique=False)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    following = models.BooleanField()

class Articles(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', related_name='articles')
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=300, blank=True)

class Transcripts(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', related_name='transcripts')
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=300, blank=True)
```

Below is a view for a single company, however since I'm returning all companies I obviously can't use a primarykey.  How would I go about getting this info for each of the companies?  Am I setting up my models the right way to do this?

```
class CompanyDetails(generic.DetailView):
    model = Company
    template_name = 'company_details.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        context = super(CompanyDetails, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['company'] = Company.objects.filter(id=pk)            
        context['articles'] = Articles.objects.filter(company_id=pk).order_by('-date')
        context['transcripts'] = Transcripts.objects.filter(company_id=pk).order_by('-date')
        return context
```

**UPDATE**

How do I update the template if I want to show in a column that there is at least one article tied to each company?  When I tried the for loop in the answer it created a column for every article, so I tried changing it to the below but it every records shows up as "Blank".

```
    <tbody>
        {% for company in all_companies %}
        <tr>
            <td nowrap="true"><a href="{% url 'company_details' pk=company.pk %}">{{ company.company_name }}</a></td>
            <td nowrap="true">{{ company.stock_symbol }}</td>
            {% if company.following %}
                <td align="center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></td>
            {% else %}
                <td></td>
            {% endif %}

            <!--HAS ARTICLE(S) FLAG -->
            {% if article in company.articles.all %}
                <td align="center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span></td>
            {% else %}
                <td>Blank</td>
            {% endif %}

            <td nowrap="true"><a href="{{ company.website }}" target="_blank">{{ company.website }}</a></td>
            <td nowrap="true">{{ company.address }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the template, you can follow the foreign key backwards from a company to its articles or transcripts.

```
  {{ company }}
  {% for company in company.articles.all %}
    {{ article }}
  {% endfor %}
```

If you use this in your detail view, you don't have to set `articles` or `transcripts` in the `get_context_data` method. You shouldn't set `context['company']` at all - the detail view does this for you.

In the list view, you can loop through the companies and access the articles and transcripts in the same way.

```
{% for company in company_list %}
  {{ company }}
  {% for company in company.articles.all %}
    {{ article }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This will cause a query for every single company in the queryset. You can prevent this by using [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).

```
Company.objects.prefetch_related('articles', 'transcripts')
```

In your list view, you can use `prefetch_related` by setting `queryset`:

```
class CompanyList(generic.ListView):
    # No need to set model now that you have set queryset
    queryset = Company.objects.prefetch_related('articles', 'transcripts')
```

If you just want to know whether or not there are associated articles or transactions, then you don't have to prefetch them. You can [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) the queryset instead:

```
from django.db.models import Count

# in your view
queryset = Company.objects.annotate(num_articles=Count('article')
```

Then in your template, you can access `company.num_articles`.

```
{% if company.num_articles %}
  Company has articles
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This makes sense, thank you.  However, I don't want to display every article, I simply want to display an icon indicating there is at least one article tied to that company.  I can't figure out how to exit the for loop with a nested if statement, and a single if statement doesn't work. (question updated above with template code)

Comment: Instead of a loop, you would use an if statement instead `{% if article company.articles.all %}...{% endif %}`. However, if you don't need to display the articles, it is more efficient to `annotate` the queryset instead. See my updated answer.